# Pandas way to get unique values in a group?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',1],['a',1],['a',1],['a',2],['b',2],['b',2],['c',3]], columns=['letters','numbers'])

    letters numbers
0   a   1
1   a   1
2   a   1
3   a   2
4   b   2
5   b   2
6   c   3
```

I need by group ('letters') the number of unique values in 'numbers'. So the output would be

```
a 2
b 1
c 1
```

Here's my (very ugly) solution. It works, but can anyone help me find a more Pythonic way to do this with `pandas`?

```
result = []
groups = list(df['letters'].unique())
for g in groups:

    filtered_df = df[df['letters'] == g]

    uniques = len(filtered_df['numbers'].unique())
    result.append((g, uniques))

[('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `nunique`

```
df.groupby('letters').numbers.nunique()
Out[864]: 
letters
a    2
b    1
c    1
Name: numbers, dtype: int64
```